# plotly dash webpage works on Raspberry Pi BUT can't access it over a LAN

Tags: plotly-dash

I have started playing with Dash which is EXCELLENT for me as I don't want to be a web coder. the web page is GREAT on host machine  localhost 127.0.0.1:8050

BUT I cannot get at the web page using  192.168.1.216:8050 on the same LAN?

I checked the ports on the raspberry pi and it's listening on 8050
also I am logged in as the same user on both the remote and the hosting machines.

is there something I am missing here?  Here is the print out

```
Running on http://192.168.1.202:8050/
Debugger PIN: 086-877-772
 * Serving Flask app "5 26 20  dash datatable drop select csv" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
[31m   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.[0m
[2m   Use a production WSGI server instead.[0m
 * Debug mode: on
```

Comment: When you start a dash application, it prints out a few lines (including it's address). Could you please add these to the post?

Comment: hi @Roy2012   got an answer BUT I did as you suggested. Thank you for taking an interest. NOW I can access the web page on the local machine using http://192.168.1.216:8050  BUT the moment I try from another machine 192.168.1.202  the browser just sits there finally a message "the connection has timed out".  So I am a little closer :-)

Comment: Are you sure it's the right address? In the question, the address is 192.168.1.202:8050, while in the comment it's 192.168.1.216:8050.

Comment: Also - can you reach other services (i.e. ssh) on your raspberry pi (from other machines on the same network?)

Comment: hi @Roy2012 I run a headless pi on 192.168.1.216 and manage it from 192.168.1.202 ( ubuntu desktop) using ssh just fine, so at least that works :-)  I am running the code the pi (216) and browsing to the pi (202) from 216. The SIMPLE page works fine but the more complex one does NOT. I think this might be some kind of timing issue.

Comment: If a simple page works, but more complex pages don't, perhaps your pi isn't strong enough to run sophisticated dash pages.

Comment: Yep thought about that so I tried it on a desktop with 8gb ram and the same thing happened. thanks for all the help though. Looks like I will move onto Julia instead which is a shame.  I really liked python pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dash class uses 127.0.0.1 as a default IP address. Did you set the host parameter in the run_server() method?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, host="192.168.1.216", port=8050)
```